# What circumstances grant me the Nice/Great/Excellent catch from my Buddy?

Tags: pokemon-go

So when the buddies came out, they were given bonuses like being able to bounce the ball back at the Pokémon you are trying to catch, for a guaranteed hit. However lately, I have noticed that I am rarely getting the "Nice", "Great" or "Excellent" bonuses from this anymore, whereas originally it would be pretty much guaranteed.

Is this intended functionality, and if so, what are the circumstances (i.e. percent chance, or timing?) that do allow me to gain the extra benefits of a Nice/Great/Excellent throw when my Buddy hits the ball back at the Pokémon I am trying to catch?

EDIT: I'll point out the obvious, and go through the steps of what (should) happen, then clarify my issues.

1. I wait until the circle is small enough for a Great/Excellent throw
2. I throw the ball, and the Pokémon "attacks", deflecting the throw. This also makes the circle "disappear" during the animation.
3. My Buddy Pokémon bounces the ball back. This *always* hits the Pokémon dead center of where the circle would be.

From what I've seen, this does not always award the throw bonus (nice/great/excellent), either as part of the catch animation, or as part of the report on a successful catch. It does sometimes, other time it doesn't, and I don't know why it's inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, it  is based on whether the ball was landing in the circle (if it was there) and what size it was (if it was there). So if you throw it whilst the Pokemon is attacking, you should still aim for the middle. And have the circle locked in small.

Comment: While this works like 90% of the time, I have seen where the throw would have been excellent based on the size of the circle and the bounce back was just nice, or where a throw shouldn't have gotten any modifier and was bounced back as a great throw. So it seems like there is some other factor or randomness involved.

Comment: It's definitely based on the size of the circle before the mon started attacking, but I've seen plenty of cases where my throw would have landed well outside the circle but I still got the bonus (in fact, I've taken advantage of this on multiple occasions to more easily complete "make an excellent throw" tasks), and cases where the opposite happened as well.

Comment: In my situations I would be lined up for a great throw, or a nice throw, and I get nothing.